# Looking for new money app

Tags: iphone-app, ipad-app

I’ve used Mint/Quicken for eons. It’s easy and free. But recently I’ve needed to delve into my finances more by categorizing expenditures and making a budget. (Projections would also be nice.) It would be nice to have this all in one app. Mint will not let you categorize in their app. And when I go to their site and try to change things on my iPad, everything is too small and complicated. So I’m looking for something different. I’ve found some that will do these things but for $10/mo or more. That seems a little ridiculous for my needs. I’m willing to pay $2-3/mo for something that works for me. So.....recommendations? I have lots of accounts, mostly cc’s and no investments.

Comment: I'm sorry that you couldn't get an answer from the community. I used Quicken back in 1990 and loved it. It seemed to me that after 2003, it started getting glitchy, overstuffed, trying to sell me on things I didn't need, and not so much fun to use. Not sure where to go from here.  I last used the 2013 version, then stopped using anything, and I want to pick up where I left off, but only if Quicken has improved. YNAB is $$; Not sure that's the right tool for me. Willing to pay for something good.